# mysql query listing in the title of the input field

Tags: php

I have 3 Tables:

1.Personal - with the list fo the workers.
2.Codes - with the list of the shift.
3.Dienstplan - that like a working schedule

I have a following query

```
$query4 = $db->query("SELECT count(codes.lcfruh) AS front_lcfruh, name
FROM dienstplan
LEFT JOIN codes ON (dienstplan.schicht = codes.lcfruh)
LEFT JOIN personal ON personal.perso_id = dienstplan.perso_id
WHERE personal.status_sum = 'rezeption' AND dienstplan.kw = '$kw' AND dienstplan.schicht!='' AND personal.zeigen='ja' GROUP BY dienstplan.datum");
```

I want to have a count(codes.lcfruh) listed as in the inputfields listed as follows:

```
$names = array();
while ($result = $query4 ->fetch_object()) {
$names[] = $result->name;
echo '<p class="taglist1"><input name="" type="text" title="'.implode(', ', $names).'"     class="zbroj'.$result->front_lcfruh.'" value="'.$result->front_lcfruh.'"></p>';
}
```

The result should be an array of 7 input fields with the count of count(codes.lcfruh) for every day in the week. I am getting the correct number of fields (7) and the count in the fields correctly. Now I wanted to list the names in the title="'.implode(', ', $names).'" of the fields that are having one of the codes in the codes table column "lcfruh". The problem is I am getting only one name listed for the first days, 2 names on the second day an so on.... And it is always the first name in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just selecting the name, make a `GROUP_CONCAT` on it. As you have a `GROUP BY`, this gives you all names of that day separated by a comma.

```
SELECT count(codes.lcfruh) AS front_lcfruh, GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS name
```

Then in your echo just show the concated names like this:

```
echo '<p class="taglist1"><input name="" type="text" title="'.$result->name.'"     class="zbroj'.$result->front_lcfruh.'" value="'.$result->front_lcfruh.'"></p>';
```

Comment: I do not think that GROUP_CONCAT work in this case, I have tried it. IMy title is empty in this case.

Comment: how can get a list of results one under another  in this case.